# SELECT command denied to user ''@'localhost' for table 'tasks'

Tags: php, sql, phpmyadmin, xampp

I keep getting that error even though all the privileges have been provided to the localhost. I can insert data from same username/pass but it doesn't retrieve it.

I have already tried the methods of commenting the lines in **config.inc.php** and executing **GRANT**.

Here's my code below

```
<?php
        $servername = "localhost";
        $username = "root";
        $password = "";
        $dbname = "to_do_list";

        // Create connection
        $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
        // Check connection
        if ($conn->connect_error) {
            die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
        } 

        $query = "SELECT `task`, `date_of_task`, `time_of_task`,`id`  FROM `to_do_list`.`tasks`;"; 

       $result = mysql_query($query) or die($query."<br/><br/>".mysql_error());


      while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){         
        echo "<tr>".
        "<td>" . $row['task'] . "</td>".
        "<td>" . $row['date_of_task'] . "</td>".
        "<td>" . $row['time_of_task'] . "</td>".
        "<td> <button value=\"Edit\" class=\"btn btn-warning\"> </td>".
        "<td> <button value=\"Edit\" class=\"btn btn-warning\"> </td>".
        "</tr>";  
        }
        mysql_close();
    ?>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Do you get an error from $conn->connect_error?

Comment: btw.: You can omit the database name in the `FROM` clause. The Database is preselected by the connection.

Comment: @Robert I get error at that point
 $result = mysql_query($query) or die($query."<br/><br/>".mysql_error());
I have checked by removing it and then executing the code. That works fine

Comment: @u-nik was getting an error "**No Database Selected**", that's why added it.

Comment: your right. You have to use `mysqli_select_db`. Anyway, is not the topic here.

Comment: Can you please give me the mysql_error()?

Comment: This is the whole error message that gets printed from mysql_error()

**SELECT command denied to user ''@'localhost' for table 'tasks'**

Comment: What version of php are you using?

Comment: PHP version 5.5.28

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing to the following code solved my problem. I think it was maybe due to the conflict of using **query** as a variable.

```
$sql = "SELECT task,date_of_task,time_of_task,id  FROM to_do_list.tasks;";
$result = $conn->query($sql) or die($sql."<br/><br/>".mysql_error());


if ($result-> num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
```

Comment: Naming the variable $query or $sql makes no difference for PHP.

Answer (score 0):

I do see an extra semicolon at the end of your query:

```
$query = "SELECT ... FROM `to_do_list`.`tasks`;";
```

As well the MySQL you are using is deprecated.

Comment: I have also tried removing and then executing it. Getting the same error.

Comment: The ; at the end of the statement is necessary because php.

Answer (score 0):

You are opening a connection with MySQLi:

```
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
```

Then you are using mysql_* functions:

```
$result = mysql_query($query) or die($query."<br/><br/>".mysql_error());

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
```

Change your code to use only [MySQLi functions](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli.php), and the error will disappear.